# How can I show server logs in Visual Studio Live Server?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the Live Server extension in Visual Studio Code. It is a popular plugin for hosting, well, simple local http servers on the localhost.

In other simple servers (like Python's http.server), I get a log of the different requests and their results. How can I display a log of connections in VSCode?

Comment: I skimmed through the settings and found nothing, and searched https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aritwickdey%2Fvscode-live-server%20createOutputChannel&type=code, and found nothing (see also https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#OutputChannel). I think you might need to raise a feature request. If you think so and you do, please add a link here to it for posterity.

Comment: Looks like the project might be dead, no updates in 9 months and the issues page has no developer activity

Comment: well, I'd still encourage you to raise an issue ticket. be the change.